# i am trying to fetch the whole data based on activity_created_on key from this sample data:

Tags: python

my sample data:

```
a = [
            {
                "activity_message": "message 1",
                "activity_created_on": 1677672546
            },
            {
                "activity_message": "message 2",
                "activity_created_on": 1677672552
            },
            {
                "activity_message": "message 3",
                "activity_created_on": 1677672536
            },
            {
                "activity_message": "message 4",
                "activity_created_on": 1677672539
            }
        ]
```

i am trying to fetch the whole data based on activity_created_on key from this smaple data:

i tried in this way in python

```
def tags(a):
    for item in a:
        tags = []
        if item:
            q = {"am":item.get([]),"d":item["activity_created_on"]}
            tags.append(q)
    return tags
print(tags(a))
```

trying the outcome: could you please help me?

```
[      
               {
                "activity_message": "message 3",
                "activity_created_on": 1677672536
                },
                {
                "activity_message": "message 4",
                "activity_created_on": 1677672539
                },
                {
                "activity_message": "message 1",
                "activity_created_on": 1677672546
                },
                {
                "activity_message": "message 2",
                "activity_created_on": 16776725352
                }
            ]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sort a list of dictionaries by a value of the dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-a-value-of-the-dictionary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be solved by using `sorted` function with specified `lambda` for sort the data by `activity_created_on`

```
def sortByActivityCreatedOn(a):
  return sorted(a, key=lambda x: x['activity_created_on'])

print(sortByActivityCreatedOn(a))
```